# How to reduce the Select Apex calls in a multi level situation like this?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to reduce the Apex calls in the following situation:

For every account, I have a string ID, that is the ID of the Bill_to_account for that account (kind of financial hierarchy) (NOT Hierarchy parent)

While creating an oppty, any account can be the oppty's account, but for that account, I need to get the Account object of the one marked as: Billto_account.

Currently I have 2 calls:

```
Account oppty_account = [Select Id FROM Account where Id = :opp.AccountId];
Account billto_account = [Select Id FROM Account where Id = :oppty_account.billto_id];
```

Where the first gets the oppty's account, and the second one retrieves the billto_account that is set on the oppty's account.

Just trying to be more efficient here.

EDIT:
thanks, it's not a lookup (unfortunately) - It's a StringId that gets it's value from a trigger.
I think maybe the approach needs to be that I set the field as a lookup ?

EDIT:
The specific field with current behavior can't be changed to lookup due to other uses it has.

Comment: I added an answer, but it may not work for you if when you say "String ID" you don't mean a lookup. If you are just storing the ID of the field on the object as Text, you won't be able to use the relationship in a SOQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you be able to reference that account [like any other lookup](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)?

```
Account oppty_account = [SELECT Id, BillTo_Id__c, BillTo_Id__r.Id, FROM Account WHERE Id = :opp.AccountId];
```

So when you need the Bill To account, you can access it as:

```
oppty_account.BillTo_Id__r.Id
```

Comment: It's not a lookup, but This might be the solution? set as lookup from the trigger.

Comment: Potentially. Why not just make the field a lookup to begin with? You can still just set the Id programmatically.